# Eliminating lag when remapping 'd' key in VIM

Tags: vim, macvim

I use a Dvorak keyboard layout, and so I've made a few adjustments to the default VIM mappings-- one change I've made is to remap the right-side home row keys to

```
noremap d h
noremap h j
noremap t k
noremap n l
```

So that movement keys are conveniently positioned, as they would be for a QWERTY user.  `h`, `t`, and `n` do their job fine and are very responsive.  `d`, however, lags for a moment before moving left the way its supposed to.  I think this is because there are key-sequence commands that start with `d` (like `dd` for delete line), so VIM is waiting to receive the second stroke in the sequence before executing the command for just a single 'd'.  I've remapped `dd`:

```
noremap dd hh
```

But this isn't doing the trick.  Yet commands for things like `d3w` or `d$` (text objects after `d`) aren't working (after remapping `d`), so they couldn't be causing the issue.  Anyone know how to get rid of the lag?  BTW, even after disabling all plugins I have the same issues.  I also have no other mappings with `d` in my vimrc.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, `d`, `c` and their "operator pending" friends are not *really* mappings. This means that you can't `:unmap d`. The delay you experience can't really be avoided without side effects, I believe.

You might want to play with `:h timeout` and `:h timeoutlen`.

For what it's worth, the alternative layouts/Vim story is… complicated. [And not settled at all.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout)

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the link.  Inspired by a suggestion in that article, I think I may try to just move all the movement commands right by one key so that all the movement keys are actually directly under my right fingers on the home row.  I had remapped `k` to `d`, but I can put `d` back and just remap `k` to `s`.