# Why does Vim delay on this remapped key? And how do I fix it?

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my vimrc:

`noremap g b
vnoremap g b`

The goal of these is pretty clear: move one word to the left whenever I press g.

My issue is that there is a delay of about 1/2 second before vim executes the move. It is as if vim is waiting for me to enter an addition command.

I know vim does this kind of thing when it is expecting more information. However, this is the only case where I have a remap that involves g, so it's unlikely to be the case.

Other people seem to be having similar problems: [Eliminating lag when remapping 'd' key in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322998/eliminating-lag-when-remapping-d-key-in-vim)

But no one has yet offered a solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As progo said, Vim has many default bindings that starts with `g`. It probably isn't a key you want to bind to as a one key command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I do this and start vim using `vim -u NONE -N` I can't replicate the behaviour. Looking further, this seems to be caused by the netrw plugin, which maps the `gx` key as well as the matchit plugin, that maps `g%`. (You might to check using  `:verbose :map g` to see, if there are other ambigious g mappings that could cause this and where they were defined (by the use of `:verbose`)).

So to prevent this, you should unmap those mappings and then the `g` works without delay. But as progo already said, you lose all those nice builtin `g<x>` commands, so I would not recommend to map `g` away

Note also, recent vims have the `<nowait>` modifier, so you can just do `noremap <nowait> g b` and no delay will occur.

Comment: In addition to this, the length vim waits before mapped key sequence to complete is determined by `timeoutlen`. So even without `<nowait>`, one can `:set timeoutlen` to a smaller value, making the delay reported here shorter and using keymaps like `gx` difficult.

Comment: Thank you for such a well thought out answer. I really appreciate it. <nowait> is exactly what I was looking for, and I had forgotten about :map.

Answer (score 4):

But vim *is* expecting more information. There is a bunch of normal mode key bindings that start with `g` such as (`gg`, `gd`, `gf`, `gq`, ...) and of course vim has to wait until it knows what you started to type in.

This is a situation you can't really fix without breaking lots of other mappings.