# Why might this vim mapping be slow?

Tags: vim

I have the following mapping in my vimrc:

```
noremap <leader>b :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

Unfortunately there is about a half second to second delay to display the buffer list. Is there an obvious reason for this? How might I debug it if not?

Comment: perhaps you have another mapping starting `<leader>b`?  If so, look at the `timeout` and `ttimeout` settings.

Comment: In vim, type `:map ,b` (except where `,` is your leader key), and see what appears. At jthill mentioned, if there is ambiguity, then vim gives a timeout, waiting for more key presses before deciding there is none and moving on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
:verbose noremap <leader>b
```

lists all mappings that start with `<Leader>b` (and with `:verbose`, also where they got defined). To make Vim detect the mapping faster, you need to resolve the ambiguity, either by adding more characters to make the mapping keys unique (e.g. `<Leader>bb`), or by choosing different keys that aren't yet used in another mapping (e.g. `<Leader>B`).

Comment: Or use the `<nowait>` modifier, that is available with recent Vims (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395562/why-does-vim-delay-on-this-remapped-key-and-how-do-i-fix-it/26397275#26397275))

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt But with that, the other `<Leader>b...` mappings become unavailable! You could then also remap / unmap those (which I find more clean). I'd better only use the `<nowait>` as documented, to have buffer-local mappings quickly override longer global ones.

Comment: true. just wanted to mention it

Comment: Thanks for sharing! So `ambiguity` is the key here. Existence of `<leader>ac` will slow down the execution of the `<leader>a`.